# Python to aggregating data from json

Tags: python-3.x, aggregation

I'm trying to aggregate Json data by the Key "user", sum up the value in "rank" and also append the "link", Here is a sample of the Json data:

```
    data = [{'node': {"user": 12345, "rank": 10, "text":'random long string xxxx',"link": www.link.com/useraaaa},{'node': {"user": 23456, "rank": 20, "text":'random long string yyyy',"link": www.link.com/usercccc},{'node': {"user": 23456, "rank": 5, "text":'a very long string zzzz',"link": www.link.com/userdddd},{'node': {"user": 12345, "rank": 20, "text":'a very long string jjjj',"link": www.link.com/userbbbb}];
```

I tried iterate through data and extract the "user" into a list then iterate through data again with if else statement to check if user in list append to user with the data I need but I dont think is efficient. 
I'm trying to get an outcome of below, any suggestions ?

```
agg_data = [{"user": 12345, "rank": 30, "text":['random long string xxxx','a very long string jjjj'], "link": [www.link.com/useraaaa, www.link.com/userbbbb]},{"user": 23456, "rank": 25, "text":['random long string yyyy','a very long string zzzz'], "link": [www.link.com/usercccc, www.link.com/userdddd]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is quite  inefficient but this solves the issue, it's a good task for group by usage:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    {'node': {"user": 12345, "rank": 10, "text": 'random long string xxxx', "link": "www.link.com/useraaaa"}},
    {'node': {"user": 23456, "rank": 20, "text": 'random long string yyyy', "link": "www.link.com/usercccc"}},
    {'node': {"user": 23456, "rank": 5, "text": 'a very long string zzzz', "link": "www.link.com/userdddd"}},
    {'node': {"user": 12345, "rank": 20, "text": 'a very long string jjjj', "link": "www.link.com/userbbbb"}}
]
agg_data = [
    {"user": 12345, "rank": 30, "text": ['random long string xxxx', 'a very long string jjjj'],
     "link": ["www.link.com/useraaaa", "www.link.com/userbbbb"]},
    {"user": 23456, "rank": 25, "text": ['random long string yyyy', 'a very long string zzzz'],
     "link": ["www.link.com/usercccc", "www.link.com/userdddd"]}
]


def sum_up_keys(alist):
    res = {}
    for obj in alist:
        obj = obj['node']
        obj.pop('user')
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, int):
                if k not in res:
                    res[k] = 0
                res[k] += v
            elif isinstance(v, str):
                if k not in res:
                    res[k] = []
                res[k].append(v)
    return res


keyfunc = lambda x: x['node']['user']
group = groupby(sorted(data, key=keyfunc), keyfunc)

objs = []
for k, v in group:
    obj = {'user': k, **sum_up_keys(list(v))}
    objs.append(obj)

print(objs)
```